# Create a tar archive split into blocks of a maximum size

Tags: backup, tar

I need to backup a fairly large directory, but I am limited by the size of individual files. I'd like to essentially create a `tar.(gz|bz2)` archive which is split into 200MB maximum archives. Clonezilla does something similar to this by splitting image backups named like so:

```
sda1.backup.tar.gz.aa
sda1.backup.tar.gz.ab
sda1.backup.tar.gz.ac
```

Is there a way I can do this in one command? I understand how to use the `split` command, but I'd like to not have to create one giant archive, then split it into smaller archives, as this would double the disk space I'd need in order to initially create the archive.

Comment: A related question: https://superuser.com/q/290986/11574

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: How can I split one text file into multiple *.txt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19031144/4561887)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can pipe tar to the split command:

```
tar cvzf - dir/ | split --bytes=200MB - sda1.backup.tar.gz.
```

On some *nix systems (like OS X) you may get the following error:

```
split: illegal option -- -
```

In that case try this (note the `-b 200m`):

```
tar cvzf - dir/ | split -b 200m - sda1.backup.tar.gz.
```

If you happen to be trying to split the file to fit on a FAT32 formatted drive,
use a byte limit of 4294967295. For example:

```
tar cvzf - /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/ | \
split -b 4294967295 - /Volumes/UNTITLED/install_macos_sierra.tgz.
```

When you want to extract the files use the following command (as of @Naftuli Kay commented):

```
cat sda1.backup.tar.gz.* | tar xzvf -
```

Comment: Will `cat sda1.backup.tar.gz.* | tar xzvf -` do the job?

Comment: Yes, it should. `split` by default sets the names the files so that when sorted by LOCALE (which is done by shell globbing) will be in the correct order.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Using cat on Command line works fine. But when I do the same using a she'll Script, I am thrown at error saying the file.tar.gz.* not found.

Comment: Without verbose, just do `tar czf ...` without the `v` and merge by `cat backup.tar.gz.* | tar tar xzf - ` without `v`. I see no benefit of the verbose output here by `v`.

Comment: how does it work for .bz2.aa or .bz2.bb uncompressing ?

Comment: @Praneeth exactly the same. `cat foo.bz2.* | tar xvf -`

Comment: Just helped a friend by packing Xcode onto a FAT32 formatted flash drive with: ```tar cvzf - Xcode.app/ | split -b 2000m - /Volumes/PH/xcode/xcode.tgz``` (used from ```cd /Applications/```) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 22):

### `tar` split archive

I found this to be the best solution for a few reasons:

- It creates parts without interaction, automatically naming parts
- You can use any compression you want, usual `tar` options
- Requires **no external** commands for splitting or joining
- Uses no extra disk space (intermediate)
- Any dearchiver handles easily as each archive is **self-contained**
- Increase safety as each archive is self-contained, files do not span multiple archives

This command is creating 2GB chunks without the compression:

```
tar -cv --tape-length=2097000 --file=my_archive-{0..50}.tar file1 file2 dir3
```

- **c** for create
- **v** for verbose, to list files added to the archive
- **--tape-length** is chunk size: you can add a suffix, if you omit it, a kilobyte is assumed (hence 2 million for a 2 gigabyte)
- **--file** is where we *magically* create names for chunks: we give arbitrarily 50 but you may put any big enough number, only those needed will be used
- list of files and directories to be included in archives

Similarily, this command is creating 1GB chunks with the **gzip** compression:

```
tar -czv --tape-length=2097000 --file=my_archive-{0..50}.tar.gz file1 file2 dir3
```

Comment: Note that (I'm pretty sure) the `tar` file won't be broken at file boundaries, meaning half a file can be in one tar archive, and the other half is in the next tar archive. At least, that seems to be the case from the errors I'm seeing when trying to extract a single tar archive ("Unexpected EOF in archive"). Just mentioning this to help others in my situation. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I would use `--file=my_archive.tar.gz.{00..50}` instead, for two reasons: First, placing the number at the end indicates that the file is just a part of a larger archive.  Second, using fixed-width numbers will sort the files correctly when using cat to recombine the pieces.

Comment: @MacMladen When I try to use compression option I get an error that can't use compression. any idea on how to add compression?

Comment: @Sruly the command typed exactly should not yield any error. Can you post the exact error? (copy/paste output in terminal)

Comment: @MacMladen This is the results.
`tar -cz --tape-length=209700 --file=my-ubuntu22-fs-{00..50}.tar.gz ubuntu22-fs`
tar: Cannot use multi-volume compressed archives
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: The resulting archives are **not self-contained** in my case. `tar -tvf ./my_archive-3.tar` lists `<somefile>--Continued at byte 148992--` at the top and `tar: Unexpected EOF in archive` at the bottom

Comment: how do you unpack the files afterwards?

Comment: After much trail and error I found the best way to unpack the archive afterwards was like: `tarcat my_archive-*.tar | tar -xf -` Using the `tarcat` script from [GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/utils/tarcat.html).

Answer (score 21):

On macOS, the `split` command works slightly differently:

```
$ tar cvzf - foo | split -b 2500m - foo.tgz.
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to add: As the maximum allowed file size in vfat/fat32 is 2^32 minus 1 (4294967295 bytes), the split command with the maximum allowed file size on such file system is:

```
split -b4294967295 -d my_input_file my_output_file_splitted
```

Answer (score 4):

```
serega@serega-sv:~$ tar -c  -M --tape-length=1024 --file /tmp/pseudo-tape.tar --new-volume-script=/tmp/new-volume.sh --volno-file=/tmp/volno /tmp/stuff-to-archive 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
moving /tmp/pseudo-tape.tar to /tmp/archive.1
moving /tmp/pseudo-tape.tar to /tmp/archive.2
moving /tmp/pseudo-tape.tar to /tmp/archive.3
```

You'll need a script for automation moving pseudo-tape.tar file to a new name:

```
serega@serega-sv:~$ cat /tmp/new-volume.sh 
dir="/tmp"
base_name="pseudo-tape.tar"
next_volume_name=`echo -n "archive."; cat $dir/volno`
echo "moving $dir/$base_name to $dir/$next_volume_name"
mv "$dir/$base_name" "$dir/$next_volume_name"
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer, because I am happy to see one that uses `-M --tape-length`. However, this answer does ignore the OP's request for a solution that uses gzip or bzip2 compression.

Comment: Caution: you are not talking about `tar` but rather about a tar clone called `gtar` (GNU tar). This tar clone supports to create multi volume archives but with a noticeable probability is unable/unwilling to extract from those multi volume archives as it incorrectly claims that a follow up volume is not the right continuation part.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in my own contribution, I wrote an app recently that splits up tarballs along file boundaries, which you may find useful:

https://github.com/dmuth/tarsplit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tar I'd use 7zip or some other archiver that can natively split archive of file boundaries.

With split command you may have roubles recovering faulty archives when just one part of the series gets damaged.

7z and some other archives additionally may create recovery sum added to archives or even have option to add recovery volume that saves your day when you loose or damage entire part.