# Putting m files in a directory into n tar files by size?

Tags: linux, tar, compression

Does anyone know if it's possible to create n `tar` files (of roughly equal size) out of a larger collection of files in a directory, in such a way that they can be extracted individually?

I was looking at `tar --multi-line` option, but unfortunately it looks like ALL of the resulting `tar` files are necessary to extract the original files. Even more so with `tar`-ing then `split`-ing the files.

If they didn't have to be roughly the same size, I'd say do `ls | wc` to get the number of files in the directory, then split the filenames into equal-sized sets (something like: `ls | tail -n900| head -n100`), and pass those to `tar`. But you may end up with pretty large size variations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Tar directory into independent archive files no larger than a certain size](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281735/86440).

Comment: This is a variation of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  You won't find a simple solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a script that looks at the sizes of the files and [distributes them into bins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), taking care not to exceed the maximum size.
The optimal solution may not be simple, but a greedy algorithm should do.

A minor problem would be taking into account the bookkeeping space taken by `tar` in addition to the file contents. (Also, how to deal with directories and special files?)

A bigger problem will appear if you want to compress the archives. Since the usual idiom is to put the files together with `tar` and compress the tar file with a separate utility, it's not that simple to split the resulting archive along file boundaries. You'd pretty much need to know the compressed sizes of the files in advance. If you compress the files before `tar`ing them together, you know the sizes, but lose the space advantages of compressing all files in one go.

---

Actually, I made a simple `awk` script to do just that at some point. Code below, use with

```
find dir/ -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | awk -vmax=$maxsizeinbytes -f pack.awk
```

(Output goes to `bins.list.NNN`. No warranty, won't work with filenames containing whitespace, probably other bugs too etc.)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
# pack.awk
{ 
    if ($1 > max) {
        printf "too big (%d, max %d): ", $1, max, $2 > "/dev/stderr";
        exit 1;
    }
    for (x in bins) {
        if (free[x] >= $1) { 
            bins[x] = bins[x] "\n" $2; 
            count[x]++; free[x] -= $1; 
            next 
        }
    }; 
    bins[++i] = $2; free[i] = max - $1; count[i] = 1;
} 
END {
    for (i in bins) {
        printf "bin %d: entries: %d size: %d \n", i, count[i], max - free[i]; 
        print bins[i] > "bins.list." i
    }
}
```