# What is a great way to list files found in a directory that add up to a certain file size

Tags: awk, find, ls

This list will then be used to create tar balls for easy movement. This is what I came up with so far. Add up files that are just greater than 10GB list them to file.

```
find .  -type f -exec ls -al {} + | awk '{ total += $5 }; {print $9}; {if (total > 10000000000) {print total; total = 0  }}; END { print total }' > /tmp/testfile.txt
```

What I would like to do name each tar ball with a unique name but I am putting all results in the /tmp/testfile.txt

Tried this but seems a little cumbersome.

```
find . -type f -exec ls -al {} + | awk '{ filenumber };{ total += $5 }; {print $9}; {if (total > 10000000000) {print total; total = 0; filenumber++;print "This is filenumber"filenumber".tar" }}; END { print total }' > /tmp/testfile.txt
```

This is what I came up with -

```
 find ./ -type f -exec ls -al {} + | awk 'BEGIN { filenumber };{ total += $5 }; {print $9 > "filename"filenumber".txt"}; {if (total > 10000000000) {print total; total = 0; filenumber++;print "This is filename"filenumber".txt" }}; END { print total }' > filecheck.txt
```

After that command I feed results to this command.

```
for file in $( find . -name "filename*.txt" -type f );do tar -cvf "$file.tar" -T "$file"; done
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but.... I'm not sure about your basic premise. What about [Create a tar archive split into blocks of a maximum size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size)?

Comment: How are you transferring these files when you have them? Why 10GB?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have 100GB of data to move, splitting a large tar is not an option due to technical constraints. There is a data checker that finds the tar splits and dumps them as corrupted files. 10GB is a manageable size for NFS and rsyncing. So what I did was create a list of files that sum up in size of 10GB, that list is then fed to a tar command.

Comment: Look up knapsack algorithms

Comment: Let me try the knapsack algorithm, sounds promising.

Comment: @LCJ Actually, what you want is "bin packing" not "knapsack".

Comment: @Kaz Thanks for the info. I never heard of "bin packing" and fits the description.