# cp: error writing '/location-to-file/file.zip': File too large

Tags: files, cp, mv, fat

**Log**:

```
~$ cp -r folder /media/usr/media-name/
cp: error writing '/location-to-file/file.zip': File too large
```

**Question**: How to copy large files/folders to media in Linux?

---

#### Excess Details

500 GB Sandisk Drive
(recently formatted to FAT using GNOME Disks)

Folder of under 20 GB

Comment: FAT 32 has a 4GB maximum file size. The '32' is a bit-size built into the FAT structures, and 2^^32 is 4GB. So your .zip file can't be written to it. Linux is best with ext4 or ext3 file systems, exFAT and NTFS are possible, but FAT is a bad choice.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size/61776#61776

Answer (score 13):

FAT 32 has a 4GB maximum file size and 8TB maximum partition size, whereas you can store files that are larger than 4GB each on a flash drive or SD card formatted with exFAT. exFAT's maximum file size limit is 16EiB (Exbibyte).

Comment: 16 EiB (Exbibyte) is enormous! Just in case anybody is wondering if it would be enough, hahah