# How do i split my tar.gz into multiple files in a single exec command?

Tags: tar, split

I don't know anything about Unix/Linux. I am primarily a web programmer.

I am running the following command in my code:

```
exec("tar -caf '/backups/_structure.tar.gz' --ignore-failed-read -C /source .");
```

This code makes a file backup of all the contents of my `/source` directory and stores it in the `/backup` directory. This code works fine, except for the fact that sometimes my files are HUGE.

I would like to split the tar file by 100MB segments. In this single line, what would I add to do that? I've read some things about `| split -b 100MB`, but I don't know where in the line to put it and I'm very confused.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61774/create-a-tar-archive-split-into-blocks-of-a-maximum-size

Answer (score 2):

```
tar -cf - --ignore-failed-read -C /source . | gzip |
  split -b 100M - /backups/_structure.tar.gz.
```

The whole point of `tar` is that it sends a stream, that we compress on the fly, split on the fly, send over the network, etc with pipelines without ever having to store temporary files.

`-f -` tells `tar` to send the archive on stdout, which here is connected via a pipe to `gzip`, which compresses it on the fly and sends it to `split`.

`-` tells `split` to take its input from stdin. The second argument is the prefix for the chunks. See the man page of `split` for how to change the naming scheme for those chunks if you don't like the default.

Same thing, to  extract that archive, no need to store the full `tar.gz` file, just use:

```
cat _structure.tar.gz.* | gunzip | (cd /dest && tar xf -)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create the tar file:

`tar -caf '/backups/_structure.tar.gz' --ignore-failed-read -C /source .`
Then, `split` the tar file in 100Mbs

`split -b 100M /backups/_structure.tar.gz`

This will create a file with weird names, like xaa, xab...

To have the original file again, just `cat` all those files:

`cat xaa xab xac... > _structure.tar.gz`